# NodeJS new process (.fork) creating an extra process?

Tags: node.js, process, fork

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious, but when I fork a new process in NodeJS it creates 2 extra new processes. I'm trying to understand why the extra one is being created? (I'm on Windows).

If I run the main app alone and I open my task manager it only shows 1 node process running. But once I fork the process it shows 3 when I'm expecting it to show 2. Where is the extra process coming from? (I have nothing in my code that would create another one within the new process, I've tried this on a empty file to double check).

Comment: Show us some code.

Comment: Please show us your exact code you are using to fork.  Questions about code SHOULD always include the relevant portions of your code.  We can always help more specifically if we can see your actual code and we can even find things wrong that you didn't know to ask about or suggest even better ways to solve the problem.

Comment: It's a blank file with the code copied from the NodeJS website. If I run it in another directory it only starts 2 processes but when I run it in my main directory with the rest of the code removed/commented it starts 3 processes